# Question about integration of differential forms

Tags: integration, differential-topology, differential-forms

In my notes of differential topology, I read the following:

> If $\omega$ is a $n$-form on $\mathbb{R}^n$, then $\int_Ud\omega=0$ (if the form has compact support).

However, if I differentiate the $1$-form on $\mathbb{R}^2 \omega = y^2dx+xdy$ and then integrate on a generic compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$, I don't get zero. Where am I wrong?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: When you differentiate an $n$-form you get an $n+1$ form, which is always zero (regardless compactness). Your $\omega$ is a $1$-form, not a $2$-form.

Comment: Your $\omega$ does not have compact support.

Comment: Can you tell me an example of differential form with compact support? Thanks

Comment: Mattecapu thanks that is clear to me, my question is different

Comment: You mean to say that $\omega$ is a compactly-supported $(n-1)$-form. But what is $U$?